# Secrets in Nextjs client build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables, next.js13

In NextJs secrets are divided into client and backend secrets, as it is said in the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser if you prefix the variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_ this variable will end up in the frontend bundle.

Also here in the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/env it says that the way it works is that variables are replaced at build time with the value of the env variable.

We have a problem in a project that variables not marked as NEXT_PUBLIC_ are undefined in the production build, we would have to provide them to the docker and we want to avoid that, and my question is, if i name variable NEXT_PUBLIC_SOME_SECRET, but not use it in the frontend code, only in the api route, will the value be just replaced with the value of the variable by the bundler at build time, or would those really end up in the frontend bundle?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Did you add your env variables to the server?
If you have already not, then;

For `vercel`:

- you should navigate to your `project screen`
- on the top side, you have the `settings` tab.
- on that page, you will have a side menu on the left. So choose the `Environment Variables` there and add your `env variables` to the server too.